# Bash script to archive files and then copy new ones

Tags: bash, shell, archive

Need some help with this as my shell scripting skills are somewhat less than l337 :(

I need to gzip several files and then copy newer ones over the top from another location. I need to be able to call this script in the following manner from other scripts.

```
exec script.sh $oldfile $newfile
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** To add more detail:

This script will be used for monthly updates of some documents uploaded to a folder, the old documents need to be archived into one compressed file and the new documents, which may have different names, copied over the top of the old. The script needs to be called on a document by document case from another script. The basic flow for this script should be -

1. The script file should create a new gzip
   archive with a specified name (created from a prefix constant in the script and the current month and year e.g. prefix.september.2009.tar.gz) only if it
   does not already exist, otherwise add to the existing one.
2. Copy the old file into the archive.
3. Replace the old file with the new one.

Thanks in advance,
Richard

**EDIT:** Added mode detail on the archive filename

Comment: Ok, but since you want to store more than one file as a single compressed file, you now also need to specify the archive filename as an extra argument, since it can no longer be determined from oldfile (you could add oldfile to any existing archive, or you might want to create a new one). Can you address how you want this to work in your workflow?

Comment: Question Updated: The filename should be created from a prefix constant within the script and the current month and year e.g. fileprefix.month.year.tar.gz

Comment: I know that I can format the file name using something similar to PREFIX="fileprefix";FILENAME=$(date +"$PREFIX.%B.%Y.gz) but how do I check if it exists, and how do I add more files if it does?

Comment: @Frozenskys: I've updated my answer. Hopefully this will give you enough of a skeleton to adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the modified script based on your clarifications. I've used `tar` archives, compressed with `gzip`, to store the multiple files in a single archive (you can't store multiple files using `gzip` alone). This code is only superficially tested - it probably has one or two bugs, and you should add further code to check for command success etc. if you're using it in anger. But it should get you most of the way there.

```
#!/bin/bash

oldfile=$1
newfile=$2

month=`date +%B`
year=`date +%Y`

prefix="frozenskys"

archivefile=$prefix.$month.$year.tar

# Check for existence of a compressed archive matching the naming convention
if [ -e $archivefile.gz ]
then
    echo "Archive file $archivefile already exists..."
    echo "Adding file '$oldfile' to existing tar archive..."
    
    # Uncompress the archive, because you can't add a file to a
    # compressed archive
    gunzip $archivefile.gz

    # Add the file to the archive
    tar --append --file=$archivefile $oldfile
    
    # Recompress the archive
    gzip $archivefile

# No existing archive - create a new one and add the file
else
    echo "Creating new archive file '$archivefile'..."
    tar --create --file=$archivefile $oldfile
    gzip $archivefile
fi

# Update the files outside the archive
mv $newfile $oldfile
```

Save it as `script.sh`, then make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Then run like so:

```
./script.sh oldfile newfile
```

something like `frozenskys.September.2009.tar.gz`, will be created, and `newfile` will replace `oldfile`. You can also call this script with `exec` from another script if you want. Just put this line in your second script:

```
exec ./script.sh $1 $2
```

Comment: That's almost it :) - but I need to be able to keep adding more files to the archive. I've updated the Question so that it better explains the flow of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You are my Hero, that's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

A good refference for any bash scripting is [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

This guide explains every thing bash scripting.

The basic approach I would take is:

```
Move the files you want to zip to a directory your create.
   (commands mv and mkdir)

zip the directory. (command gzip, I assume)

Copy the new files to the desired location (command cp)
```

In my experience bash scripting is mainly knowing how to use these command well and if you can run it on the command line you can run it in your script.

Another command that might be useful is

```
pwd - this returns the current directory
```

Comment: And don't forget error conditions.  cp, mv, gzip, etc. can all fail.  Any script you write should be as robust as possible (good habit to get into).  Check whether $oldfile and $newfile exist before trying to operate on them.  Check whether each command you write succeeds.  Perl has a nice way to do this: "some_command || die "some_command failed", but we can do that in bash too.

Comment: Good point - however I need to figure out how to get the script working before I can add in error handling :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use version control? It's much easier; just check out, and compress.

(apologize if it's not an option)

Comment: Good idea, and that's what I use for my code updates - using the excellent beanstalkapp service, but that's not an option for these documents.